# How to add zeros to numbers with uncertainty with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

### Question

Is it possible to typeset a number with uncertainty and add the zeros to both the number and the uncertainty?

### Description

I came to the conclusion that the uncertainty is breaking the formatting options but couldn't find any information about it.  Should I use other options?  Or is not possible to typeset the uncertainty with extra zeros?

What I mean is that the tabular displays of numbers `6` and `1` do not have the zeros that non uncertainty numbers have.

### Example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
scientific-notation=true,
table-format=1.1(1)e1,
separate-uncertainty,
round-integer-to-decimal,
round-mode = figures
}

\begin{document}
% these two behave the same
\num{1}
\num{1.}

% this one doesn't work
\begin{tabular}{S}
0.006(1) \\% this one has no zeros (nor decimal places)
1\\% this one is ok
1(1)% sames as the first
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### Current output

[image]

#### Expected output (without modifying the data)

[image]

Comment: Some trial and error: try `0.0060(10)` and `1.0(10)`. As to why, I cannot really say much.

Comment: Yes those are the results I was looking for. However, I was expecting to do it automatically instead of changing the original data.  Is there a way?

Comment: That one turned off the scientific notation on the first one.  And you are still changing the integer for a float on the third row.

Comment: I updated the question with the expected output given the data on the MWE.

Comment: adn, sorry, as the reason of this behavior eludes me, I haven't a clue as to how to get the desired results without changing the original data.